# WSO2 API Publisher Store Redirect

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

After Publishing an API in the API Publisher, a pop-up asks if I would like to go to the API Store.  If I select yes, it try's to go to the store using the local private IP address and fails (I need to use the public IP instead).  Where in the configuration file can I make an update to the IP/Location of the redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the url in `<URL>` element in `<APIStore>` section in api-manager.xml file (in wso2am-1.10.0/repository/conf)